# Documentation examples - exhaustive or incremental?

Tags: discussion, documentation

**TL;DR** Exactly how much goes in one example?

When looking at examples, the first thing I did was try to extend [this example on parsing timezone-aware strings](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/484/date-and-time/1592/parsing-a-string-into-a-timezone-aware-datetime-object#t=201607211931448052331) to cover other types of timezone-aware strings. This was rejected as "it should be a separate example", and I moved it to [its own example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/484/date-and-time/4539/parsing-a-string-with-a-short-time-zone-name-into-a-timezone-aware-datetime-obje#t=201607211931448052331).

In the above case, the edit turned out much longer than the original example, but I see things like ["Fuzzy datetime parsing"](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/484/date-and-time/4552/fuzzy-datetime-parsing-extracting-datetime-out-of-a-text#t=201607211928489603075) and my immediate thought is that this one example (using `fuzzy`) is not covering the use of the `fuzzy_with_tokens` topic, which is the exact same thing, but it also returns the tokens that were skipped. Should I be making a separate example "parsing fuzzy datetimes and returning the tokens" in this case, or is this a situation where it's advisable to combine them?

I've also created a [fairly thorough guide to constructing timezone-aware datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/484/date-and-time/4540/constructing-timezone-aware-datetimes#t=201607211931448052331), but there are at least three natural places to break it up. I personally like having them grouped all together as one, because it gathers the information all in one place, but if each section were an edit (and not part of the original post), I suspect they would have been rejected for being too exhaustive.

Is there guidance on what goes in an example?

Comment: Who knows...your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: I encountered the same with an example I wrote about C# exception handling. Of course you shouldn't use `catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex) }`, but I don't think Documentation is the place to write a book about proper exception handling. Those are available on Amazon already, and even better, are cross-language.

Comment: The suggestion since the start of the private beta has always been to "keep examples short and to the point"

Comment: @RobbieAverill Keep them short? Well, some examples even being kept short, could be quite long. Is 200 loc short?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's early in the life of Documentation, but I'd say error on the side of concise-ness.  Q&A still exists for very narrow questions, so examples don't need to be exhaustive.

A very rough rule of thumb, if there were 6 examples of a given size... would you expect a reasonable users to read all of them in one sitting?  There are topics that'll break the mold I'm sure, and six is pretty arbitrary (probably not too far off).  It's a starting point though.